# Burninate the [gb] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

There's only 7 questions in the [gb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gb) tag, but they all are using it for different things:

- Something to deal with Chinese encoding:  [any PHP or Ruby library to convert Tranditional Chinese to Simplified Chinese or vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856323/any-php-or-ruby-library-to-convert-tranditional-chinese-to-simplified-chinese-or) and [Windows phone 8, how StreamReader handle GB encoding text correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027782/windows-phone-8-how-streamreader-handle-gb-encoding-text-correctly)
- The GigaByte size:  [windows batch to convert bytes to GB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880236/windows-batch-to-convert-bytes-to-gb), [Gigabyte/Gibibyte format Windows Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834973/gigabyte-gibibyte-format-windows-azure), [How to get df linux command output always in GB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962041/how-to-get-df-linux-command-output-always-in-gb)
- Great Britain:  [Regional maps for United Kingdom regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275297/google-geo-charts-for-united-kingdom-regions)
- The Nintendo Game Boy: [GBDK MetaTile Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954916/gbdk-metatile-confusion)

All of these questions look like they would work fine without that tag.  I'll probably handle the removal if this is a good idea.

<sub>This is my first time doing this so I'm not sure if I did this correctly</sub>

Comment: If you do so, don't restrict yourself to just removing the tag: Edit, retag, flag and vote as appropriate.

Comment: For only seven questions, no more than three per meaning, I'm surprised you bothered to ask first.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom This was/is my first burnintate-request, so I wasn't sure quite whether I should do it like that or not.  I also wasn't sure if there were additional steps that needed to be taken afterwards, and just announcing my actions beforehand felt like a good plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like someone has completed this work.  [gb] no longer exists.